# How do I make tabu and multicol play nice with each other?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, multicol, tabu

I'm trying to write a document that will require lots of small tables (which contain other, nested tables) in a section of my document, which I want to put into a two-column section. I use `tabu` for the tables and `multicol` to get the two-column formatting for only part of the document. When I wasn't using `multicol`, I deliberately picked a sizing for my `tabu` tables to make them sit nicely by each other. However, once I introduced `multicol`, things started to get... odd.

In summary, I started with this, and it worked:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,tabu}

Some initial text goes here, that should not be in two-column format.
\begin{tabu} to 0.45/linewidth {X}
\toprule
\centering {\bf A table heading}\\
\midrule
\begin{tabular}{lp{6.2cm}}
    {\bf Text} & More text\\
     & Other text.\\
     & Yet more text.\\
\end{tabular}\\
\begin{tabular}{lp{1.6cm}p{3.8cm}}
   {\bf Text} & More complicated & table.\\
    & More & complexity.\\
\end{tabular}\\
\end{tabu}
\begin{tabu} to 0.45/linewidth {X}
\toprule
\centering {\bf Another table heading}\\
\midrule
\begin{tabular}{lp{6.2cm}}
    {\bf Text} & More text\\
     & Other text.\\
     & Yet more text.\\
\end{tabular}\\
\begin{tabular}{lp{1.6cm}p{3.8cm}}
   {\bf Text} & More complicated & table.\\
    & More & complexity.\\
\end{tabular}\\
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

Then, I tried to wrap the two `tabu` tables in a `multicols` as follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,tabu,multicol}

Some initial text goes here, that should not be in two-column format.
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{tabu} to 0.45/linewidth {X}
\toprule
\centering {\bf A table heading}\\
\midrule
\begin{tabular}{lp{6.2cm}}
    {\bf Text} & More text\\
     & Other text.\\
     & Yet more text.\\
\end{tabular}\\
\begin{tabular}{lp{1.6cm}p{3.8cm}}
   {\bf Text} & More complicated & table.\\
    & More & complexity.\\
\end{tabular}\\
\end{tabu}
\begin{tabu} to 0.45/linewidth {X}
\toprule
\centering {\bf Another table heading}\\
\midrule
\begin{tabular}{lp{6.2cm}}
    {\bf Text} & More text\\
     & Other text.\\
     & Yet more text.\\
\end{tabular}\\
\begin{tabular}{lp{1.6cm}p{3.8cm}}
   {\bf Text} & More complicated & table.\\
    & More & complexity.\\
\end{tabular}\\
\end{tabu}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

However, this made the formatting horribly broken and unreadable. I then tried to go back and wrap each `tabu' in a`table` environment as follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,tabu,multicol}

Some initial text goes here, that should not be in two-column format.
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{table}[!h]
\begin{tabu} to 0.45/linewidth {X}
\toprule
\centering {\bf A table heading}\\
\midrule
\begin{tabular}{lp{6.2cm}}
    {\bf Text} & More text\\
     & Other text.\\
     & Yet more text.\\
\end{tabular}\\
\begin{tabular}{lp{1.6cm}p{3.8cm}}
   {\bf Text} & More complicated & table.\\
    & More & complexity.\\
\end{tabular}\\
\end{tabu}
\end{table}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabu} to 0.45/linewidth {X}
\toprule
\centering {\bf Another table heading}\\
\midrule
\begin{tabular}{lp{6.2cm}}
    {\bf Text} & More text\\
     & Other text.\\
     & Yet more text.\\
\end{tabular}\\
\begin{tabular}{lp{1.6cm}p{3.8cm}}
   {\bf Text} & More complicated & table.\\
    & More & complexity.\\
\end{tabular}\\
\end{tabu}
\end{table}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

However, when I did *that*, I instead ended up with both tables *vanishing*, and just having an empty page in their place. What am I doing wrong, and how can I make all these components play nice with each other?

Comment: `0.45/linewidth` shouldn't that be `0.45\linewidth` ??

Comment: `multicol` does not support floating environments.

Comment: Have you considered using the [`floatrow`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/floatrow/) package. It will allow you to format two tables side-by-side.

Comment: Multicol will not work for floating environments. Instead try [`minipage`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes#minipage_and_parbox) or [`parallel`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/parallel).

Comment: @NictraSavios Add some minimal examples, please.

Comment: @Speravir I linked to the documentation. He can read for himself.

Comment: @NictraSavios Wrong attitude in TeX.SE … or … You can guess exactly once why your answer was converted into a comment (as a comment it is OK).

Answer (score 4):

If you use `\begin{multicols}{2}`, then `\linewidth` is not the line width of the full text body, but the line width of the column. Therefore `0.45\linewidth` is less then the half of the current column width.

Thus the example uses `.9\linewidth` and centers the tables horizontally inside the column:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,tabu,multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
Some initial text goes here, that should not be in two-column format.
\lipsum[2]
\begin{multicols}{2}
\centering
\begin{tabu} to .9\linewidth {X}
\toprule
\centering {\bf A table heading}\\
\midrule
\begin{tabular}{lp{6.2cm}}
    {\bf Text} & More text\\
     & Other text.\\
     & Yet more text.\\
\end{tabular}\\
\begin{tabular}{lp{1.6cm}p{3.8cm}}
   {\bf Text} & More complicated & table.\\
    & More & complexity.\\
\end{tabular}\\
\end{tabu}
\begin{tabu} to .9\linewidth {X}
\toprule
\centering {\bf Another table heading}\\
\midrule
\begin{tabular}{lp{6.2cm}}
    {\bf Text} & More text\\
     & Other text.\\
     & Yet more text.\\
\end{tabular}\\
\begin{tabular}{lp{1.6cm}p{3.8cm}}
   {\bf Text} & More complicated & table.\\
    & More & complexity.\\
\end{tabular}\\
\end{tabu}
\end{multicols}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: To further disambiguate the various width parameters, it might make sense to use `\columnwidth` instead of `\linewidth` in the setup of the `tabu` environment.

Comment: @Mico: The tables could be put in a `quote` environment, then `\linewidth` reflects the actual line width.